# Get multidimensional array out of query

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get multidimensional array out of query and for some reasons it does not work.

I use query to retrieve data from mysql.

```
$sql = "SELECT Id, UserID, TimeAction, Command FROM users_checked WHERE UserId = 4 AND date(TimeAction) = '2016-12-05 '";

$q=$conn->query($sql);

$data = array(); 

    while($r=$q->fetchAll((PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        $data[]=$r;
    }
```

Array output
[image: array output]

I should get array like printed below

```
$data = array(
        array(
            "Id" => "1",
            "UserID" => "1",
            "TimeAction" => "2016-11-29 08:00:00",
            "Command" => "Prijava"
        ),
        array(
            "ID" => "1",
            "USERID" => "1",
            "TimeAction" => "2016-11-29 10:05:14",
            "Command" => "Odjava"
        ),
        array(
            "Id" => "1",
            "UserID" => "1",
            "TimeAction" => "2016-11-29 12:22:14",
            "Command" => "PoslovniIzlazak"
        ),
        array(
            "ID" => "1",
            "USERID" => "1",
            "TimeAction" => "2016-11-29 13:32:14",
            "Command" => "Prijava"
        ),
        array(
            "ID" => "1",
            "USERID" => "1",
            "TimeAction" => "2016-11-29 16:00:00",
            "Command" => "Odjava"
        ),
    );
```

Comment: You have an array like you want but the representation of browser is like you show us by images. You can `var_dump()` to see array like you want now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fetchAll` - Returns an array containing all of the result set rows where as `fetch` - Fetches the next row from a result set.

So you have to use fetch instead of fetchAll if you want the data row wise.
Try this code.

```
while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $data[] = $r;
}
```

---

Reference:

- [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)
- [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_all` in your for loop, this way you can push the data you want into your array for each row of your mysql query result.
It would look like this :

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_array = array(
        "Id" => row['Id'],
        "UsedID" => row['UserID'],
        "TimeAction" => row['TimeAction'],
        "Command" => row['Command']
    );
    array_push($data, $row_array);
}
```

Please note I didn't test the code, I'm doing this by head.
Also, I'm guessing you didn't mean to write all Ids to "1" in your example.